# Fixed headers with css transitions

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following problem with transitions:

CSS

```
header {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#000;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

#content {
    height:800px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.headerSticky {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:1000;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>lala</header>
<div id="content">
    <span class="test">test</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.test').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if(direction == 'down')
    $('header').addClass('headerSticky');
  else
    $('header').removeClass('headerSticky');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SwLdb/

I have a header and I want when scroll reaches an item (using jquery waypoint ), the header to be fixed in top. But I want this with a transition so as to look nice.

Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: your fiddle link is incorrect (404)

Comment: [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwLdb/)

Comment: fiddle link incorrect in the question. Hope you know how to share the fiddle(Not the copy the current URL, but should give a share link after saving.)

Comment: Why do you need jquery waypoint http://jsfiddle.net/SwLdb/3/

Comment: sorry for the error link! I use it for specifying when to make header fixed

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this might be to animate the header to the position it needs to be at which would be `$(window).scrollTop();` and THEN change the class to headerSticky. The user would not be able to notice it, but you would get the desired effect.

```
  if(direction == 'down')
  {
    $('header').animate({top:$(window).scrollTop()},500,function()
    {
        $('header').addClass('headerSticky',500);
    }
  }
  else
    $('header').removeClass('headerSticky',500);
```